# React JS: Why is my cleanup function triggering on render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, backend

So I was following this Firebase in React Course, it was going great until I ran into an error even though I'm following the instructor.

I have this `useSign()` hook:

which I use in this `SignIn.jsx` Component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./useAuth";
import { auth } from "../firebase/config";

export default function useSignin() {
    const [unmounted, setUnmounted] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const { dispatch } = useAuth();

    const signIn = async (email, password) => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(null);
        console.log("inside signin, unmounted: ", unmounted);

        try {
            console.log("inside try, unmounted: ", unmounted);
            const res = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

            console.log("inside try after signin, unmounted: ", unmounted);
            dispatch({
                type: "LOGIN",
                payload: res.user,
            });

            console.log("inside try after dispatch, unmounted: ", unmounted);

            if(!unmounted) {
                setLoading(false);
                setError(null);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("inside catch, unmounted: ", unmounted);

            if (!unmounted) {
                setError(err.message);
                setLoading(false);
            };
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {

        return () => setUnmounted(true);

    }, []);

    return { signIn, error, loading };
}
```

`export default function SignIn() {

```
const {signIn, loading, error} = useSignin();

const handleSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("signing in...")
    signIn(e.target.email.value, e.target.password.value);

}

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={styles["signIn"]}>

    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>

    {!loading && <button type="submit">Sign in</button>}
    {loading && <button type="submit" disabled>Signing in...</button>}
    {error && <p>{error}</p>}
</form>
);
}
```

The problem is, that the **"empty-arrayed"** useEffect in the hook is triggering twice with the cleanup function being triggered in between? setting `unmounted` to true and preventing `loading` and `error` to set states, all of that while the component is still mounted. Mind you, the Instructor's code looks exactly the same as far as I can tell..

would appreciate some help.. Thanks!

I couldn't figure out a solution, all I did was debug with some console logs and apparently the problem lies in the cleanup function being triggered when the component renders..

Comment: It's probably `<StrictMode>`

Comment: @Phil Removing <StrictMode> did in fact work, but I'm not sure why..

Comment: In the useEffect Hook, instead of calling the function in the return, just return the method. React will call that method when the component is destroyed.

Comment: @BennisonJ I need to pass parameters (the new state) to the setState so I use an arrow function...